# Dependency injection example

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

There's a nice [tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/2394/dependency-injection-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial) that seems to make sense about DI and IoC

Wouldn't it be easier to make the `getCustomer` methods static in the injector classes? I don't really see any reason to instantiate injector objects in this case.

So instead of:

```
MessageServiceInjector injector = null;
Consumer app = null;

injector = new EmailServiceInjector();
app = injector.getConsumer();
app.processMessages(msg, email);
```

We would just do:

```
Consumer app = null;
app = EmailServiceInjector.getConsumer();
app.processMessages(msg, email);
```

How to write injector classes properly? At the end of the article it says

> We can achieve IoC through Factory Pattern, Template Method Design
>   Pattern, Strategy Pattern and Service Locator pattern too

but I guess none of the patterns was used in this example (IoC in this case is just simplistic). So how would it be done in a real project (assuming no external frameworks or IoC containers are used), i.e. if I wanted to create all the necessary stuff to let me use DI in my code.

Answer (score 2):

"Easier"?  I don't think it makes any difference to your DI engine.

Static would assume one instance.  What if you want an instance per request, as you might for each web request?  Static won't do then.

I've used Spring for more than ten years.  It has a bean factory and DI capability that can deal with singleton or per request instances.  Have a look at how it works to see one successful way to do it.

I think Martin Fowler's [DI article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html), now 11 years old, still explains it well.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in my question. What's the problem with having a factory class with static method returning the object I need? I can have many requests and I won't have any problems with the new instance provided by this static method. Oh, and I forgot to add I'm considering a case when no DI engine or similar stuff is in use.

Comment: It's a "factory" with a single product - not a polymorphic constructor that factory implies.  Nobody is forcing you to use anything.  Please proceed with your static data.

Comment: The example is so trivial that anything will "work", including a non-static getter.   Your question seems like a challenge: "Prove to me that DI is ever worth using."  I could care less if you accept my answer or not.

Comment: You mean that it's very likely that I'd want the objects returned by EmailServiceInjector to be different every request and then having just one static method wouldn't make much sense? Actually I could pass some data to this static method, but I guess it would be better to let the EmailServiceInjector class control the data it needs. Is that your point? I deleted my comment before you added yours, sorry if it looked bad.

Answer (score 1):

In real world project, you should use Dependency injection framework like  [Spring Framework](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/). The are other as well like[Google Guice](https://github.com/google/guice).

I have been personally using spring for couple of years now and it has grow to much larger extent apart from basic DI.

Comment: Spring has always been a three legged stool: DI, AOP, and libraries.  It's the latter that has evolved the most.  I think the proper spelling is "Guice": https://github.com/google/guice

Comment: Corrected the spelling. And yes libraries is what have evolved in spring

Answer (score 1):

> Wouldn't it be easier to make the getCustomer methods static in the injector classes?

It seems to me that what this article is calling an Injector is actually an [abstract factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). We use abstract factories when we want a class to create objects at a later point it time.

In general it is not recommended to have static methods. Mainly because the classes that call the static method will have a hard dependency on it, i.e., you cannot at a later point in time consume a different dependency without changing the consuming class code. And this is exactly the problem that DI is trying to solve.

Another reason is that it is hard to mock static methods in a unit test.

> So how would it be done in a real project?

In real projects you should construct your objects (e.g. services) in the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

There are two ways to do it. Either use a DI container, or use [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/).

In my opinion, Pure DI is a better choice. See [this article](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/08/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex.html) for a reason why.

Comment: Sounds like a guy trying to shill a book.  Funny, DI containers are used because they work.  Another guy with a "better idea" who's bitter because the world hasn't taken up his cause.

Comment: You don't know me. Please comment on the subject. Not on me.

Comment: I am commenting on the subject.  Your Pure DI idea is neither widespread nor acknowledged as a "better choice".  Factories have been common since before GoF Design Patterns.

Comment: Actually, the biggest part of your comment was not on the subject. Anyway, Pure DI is not my idea, but in my experience, I find it better. Also, when I mentioned that Pure DI is a better choice, I started the sentence with "In my opinion" and it was only the last sentence in my answer. Everything before that, is not controversial. In my referenced article, I speak why Pure DI might be a better choice, and I provide examples. You can comment on what is written there, instead of accusing me of things you don't know about.

Comment: Better - under all circumstances?  Hardly.  Accusing you?  It's the original article that's shilling a book.  You're too sensitive and self-important.

Comment: I'd say in almost all cases. If you have comments on the article, please comment on it. In all cases, please don't comment on me.

Comment: I have commented.  This isn't a new idea.  You don't agree - what a shame.  You continue to make it about you.  Classic.

Comment: Although I agree with much you say in [your article], IMO the choice you give is to black-white. I think it is good to stay away from crazy and fragile features of the DI container, and hand-wire components that have more complex needs, your article seems to imply that for that reason it is better to go with Pure DI completely. These options however aren't mutually exclusive; you can register delegates that contain hand-wired components, mixed with the bulk of your configuration being auto-wired (and preferably registered using batch-registration).

Comment: @duffymo: DI is not about tooling, it's about patterns. I agree with much that Yacoub says. Pure DI has many advantages and good design and good practices, could make DI libraries superfluous (and do note that I maintain a [DI library](https://simpleinjector.org] myself). I usually advice developers to start of with Pure DI, and switch to a DI library when maintaining the Composition Root becomes cumbersome. In the applications I write and maintain however, it wouldn't be very practical to live without a DI library.

Comment: Thanks @Steven. My main argument in the article is that OO design patterns and other OO practices push us in the direction of having what I call in the article "a complex object graph", and creating such graphs with a DI container is much less maintainable than using Pure DI. I am very interested to see the case where its hard/harder not to use a DI container, do you happen to know an open source application with such attribute?

Comment: @YacoubMassad: The applications I write (which are usually quite large) conform to SOLID and contain hundreds small (focused) classes, mostly placed behind a a few generic abstractions and often have one or multiple generic decorators (sometimes with generic type constraints) applied to them. In that case it becomes quite cumbersome to hand-wire all those classes with all those dependencies. That's when batch-registration and auto-wiring becomes really valuable. I've described this type of design [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) for instance.